# c++ std::bad_alloc on loading 1.9 million lines file of floating point values - source code provided

Tags: c++, file, pointers, c++11, vector

So I have an assignment where I read a 1.9 million lines of floating point values ( 360 floating points per row) and I need to operate on that data. Originally I had this working and I am not sure why am I getting a bad_alloc today. Here is my code. I am wondering if there is anything I can do to optimize it better - I am using vectors and I was hoping that I wouldn't have to use arrays of structs. I can simply create a struct and create an array of structs, and each struct will hold x,y and an array of floating point values. Will that make that much of a difference?

I would really appreciate any criticism of my implementation and code. Thanks!

**Implementation**

```
#include "file_parser.hpp"

Parser::Parser(char* fname){
    fileName = fname;
}

/*
*   The function parses a file that was set in the constructor
*   And returns a map of the file
*/
VectorsMap Parser::parseFile(){
    //open file
    fPtr = fopen(fileName, "r");
    total_rows = 0;
    line = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*LINE_MAX);

    //parse the file line by line
    while(fgets(line, LINE_MAX, fPtr)){
        //make sure that we do not read an empty line
        if(line[0] != '\0') {
            //send the line to be further parsed
            parseLine(line);
            //increment total rows count
            total_rows++;   
        }
    }
    return vector_points;
}

void Parser::doCleanUp(){
    fclose(fPtr);
    free(line);
    vector_points.clear();
}

/**
*   Parse a line and tokenize it
*   while extracting X and Y points
*   and vectors and put them in a VectorsMap(deifned in file_parser.h)
*/
void Parser::parseLine(char* line){
    //collection of vectors.
    std::vector<float> vectors;
    char* point;

    //grab the x and y tokens
    char* tk1 = strtok(line, ",");
    char* tk2 = strtok(NULL, ",");

    //value for indexing
    int i=0;
    char* tmp;

    //make sure we have two correct x and y points
    if(tk1 == NULL || tk2 == NULL){ return; }

    //convert the tokens to floats
    float x = strtof(tk1, NULL);
    float y = strtof(tk2, NULL);

    //create the x and y pair used to insert vectors into the map
    XYPair pair = XYPair(x, y);

    //tokenize until end of line
    while(point=strtok(NULL, ",")){
        //convert the token to float
        float f_point = strtof(point, NULL);
        //push the float to the vector
        vectors.push_back(f_point);
        i++;
    }
    //insert in the vectormap.
    vector_points.insert(VectorsPair(pair, vectors));
}

int Parser::getTotalRows(){
    return total_rows;
}
```

**Header file:**

```
//create specific types to make my life easier later on 
typedef std::pair<float, float> XYPair;

typedef std::pair<XYPair, std::vector<float> > VectorsPair;
typedef std::map<XYPair, std::vector<float> > VectorsMap;

class Parser{       
    public:
        //constructor
        Parser(char* fname);
        VectorsMap parseFile();
        int getTotalRows();
        int row_values;
        int total_rows;
        void doCleanUp();
    private:
        //collection of all x y points and their vectors 
        VectorsMap vector_points;
        FILE* fPtr; //file pointer to file to be parsed
        char *line; //line to parse file line by line
        char* fileName; //path/name of file to be parsed

        void parseLine(char* line);
};
```

Comment: "Originally I had this working and I am not sure why am I getting a bad_alloc today" - so what's changed? Your code, your structures, the volume of input data? Do you really need to read it all into memory at once?

Comment: Nothing actually changed, that is the problem... I wonder if it depends on server traffic? I do need to load the whole file at once. The system should be capable to handle this file being loaded into memory.

Comment: How many people saw the 1.9 million in the title of this question and though. "I have *got* to click on that." =P

Comment: @WhozCraig :D - It is for a High Performance computing class.

Comment: could you be running out of memory/address space? 1.9 Million x 360 floats is already ~2.5GiB

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov thanks for having good humor about the reaction. I figured it was something like that. It was the combination of 1.9-million lines and "source code provided" that tripped "ru ro.." reaction. All good, sir. Thank god its the *data file* you were referring to. =P

Comment: The server that I am running this on is specifically designed for such large data sets.

Comment: Is this a 64-bit application? If not, the server specs won't matter much

Comment: Seems to me like you're copying the entire datastructure when parseFile returns, since it returns an actual `map<pair<float,float>,vector<float>>` as opposed to a reference to the one inside the Parser class. That will double your memory requirements, even if you subsequently delete the Parser object. Depending on your code structure, you might want to avoid that.

Comment: rici, would you say that I need to return a pointer somehow?

Comment: Since vector_points is a member if your parser, you could just return a reference

Comment: or if you really want to remove it from the Parser, you can `std::move()` it, and return a `VectorsMap&&` from parseFile

Comment: On the off note : I would also suggest NOT mixing C and C++. Why use FILE when you have streams. I would suggest using "move semantics" as opposed to returning values. Smart pointer that are part of the C++11 are also worth considering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `malloc` and `fopen` when you call `parseFile` but then freeing in a separate function is extremely error prone. If you call `parseFile` twice without calling `doCleanup` then you leak memory and a file handle.

I would stop using `malloc` and `strtok`.

```
VectorsMap Parser::parseFile(){
    //open file
    std::ifstream f(fileName);
    total_rows = 0;
    std::string line;

    //parse the file line by line
    while(std::getline(f, line)){
        //make sure that we do not read an empty line
        if(line.size()) {
            //send the line to be further parsed
            parseLine(line);
            //increment total rows count
            total_rows++;   
        }
    }
    return vector_points;
}
```

And then rewrite `parseLine` to not use the horrible `strtok` function, e.g. using [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/libs/tokenizer/) or a `std::istringstream` and `std::getline`

Also note that you read the data into `vector_points` then  return a copy, that means you need twice the memory used by the data set. You could only keep one copy of the data by doing:

```
return std::move(vector_points);
```

so the data is moved into the return value, instead of copied.

Comment: those are very good suggestions that I think will work. Thank you